# Why is subject.onNext(3) printing here?

Tags: rxjs

In this code why subject.onNext(3) is printing first as I set subject.sample(500) but setTimeout(200)?

```
const Rx = require('rx');

const subject = new Rx.Subject();

const sampleObservable = subject.sample(500);

sampleObservable.subscribe(
    data => console.log(data),
    error => console.log(error),
    () => console.log('FINISHED')
);

subject.onNext(0);
subject.onNext(1);

setTimeout(() => {
    subject.onNext(2);
    subject.onNext(3);
    subject.onCompleted();
}, 200);
```

Comment: Your example doesn't quite make sense. The `sample` operator emits the most recently emitted value from `subject` periodically. In your example, this is every 500ms. The most recent value is 3. However, before `sample` can emit the most recent value, you've already completed `subject`, meaning nothing should be emitted at all. If instead you removed the completion call, then you should get 3. What value would you expect to get?

Comment: actually I was expecting nothing but instead, it prints 3.